# Slicing of an Eigen::Tensor possible with std::vector<> as indices?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

Is there any simple construct available to slice an Eigen Tensor using a std::vector<size_t> (or something similar...) for the indices? Functionally something like this:

```
std::vector<size_t> indices;
...
sliced_tensor_3D = tensor_3D(Eigen::all, indices, Eigen::all);
```

It seems to be available for the Eigen Matrix, but I can't find something similar for Tensor...